# Keep formatting of object when passing EJS object from backend to frontend

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

Please excuse me if this is a very silly question (I am relatively new to web dev.)

I am trying to pass objects from backend (NodeJS) to frontend (EJS). The object itself is being passed but the formatting is not kept.

The object in NodeJS:

```
console.log(project.output)
```

Output:

```
866-981-4022
639-714-6905
184.118.7634
232-097-6927
(513) 480-5802
```

However when I do it in HTML/EJS:

```
<div> <%= detail.output %> </div>
```

It renders like this:

```
866-981-4022 639-714-6905 184.118.7634 232-097-6927 (513) 480-5802
```

How can I fix this? I want it to print/render like it does in NodeJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the style `white-space: pre;` to the div so the new lines are rendered as is.

```
<div style="white-space: pre;"> <%= detail.output %> </div>
```

```html
<div style="white-space: pre;">866-981-4022
639-714-6905
184.118.7634
232-097-6927
(513) 480-5802</div>
```

Comment: This works! Can you also explain what exactly it does and how `white-space: pre` is different from `white-space: pre-wrap` or `pre-line` (in simple terms)?

Comment: @SavarJ. Here are the differences:
pre - makes the browser obey whitespace, newline characters like `\n` &`<br>`. pre-wrap - makes the browser obey whitespace, newline characters like `\n` &`<br>` and width of div.
pre-wrap - makes the browser obey newline characters like `\n` &`<br>` and width of div.